# same complexity code executes in Java but time limit exceeds in C++

Tags: java, c++

The following is the code for finding all possible path of a knight on a chessboard of variable size
where the initial position is given.
The java code for this problem runs fine but for C++ The time limit exceeds.

JAVA CODE

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Scanner sc  =  new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        
        int [][] path = new int[n][n];
        
        solve(r,c,path,1,n);
        
    }

    public static void solve(int r , int c , int[][] path , int move , int n) {
        
        if(r<0 || r>=n || c<0 || c>=n || path[r][c]>0)
         return;
      
    if(move == n*n)
    {
        path[r][c] = n*n;
        
        display (path,n);
        
        path[r][c] = 0;
        
        return;
    }
    
    path[r][c] = move;
    
    solve(r-2,c+1,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r-1,c+2,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r+1,c+2,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r+2,c+1,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r+2,c-1,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r+1,c-2,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r-1,c-2,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r-2,c-1,path,move+1,n);
    
    path[r][c] = 0 ;
        
        
    }
    
    
    public static void display(int [][] path , int n)
    {
        
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(path[i][j]+" ");
        }
        
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    
    System.out.print("\n");
    
    }
    
}
```

C++ code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

    
 void display( vector<vector<int>> path , int n)
    {
        
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cout<<path[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        
        cout<<("\n");
    }
    
        cout<<("\n");
    
    }



    void solve(int r , int c ,vector<vector<int>> path , int move , int n) {
        
        if(r<0 || r>=n || c<0 || c>=n || path[r][c]>0)
         return;
      
    if(move == n*n)
    {
        path[r][c] = n*n;
        
        display (path,n);
        
        path[r][c] = 0;
        
        return;
    }
    
    path[r][c] = move;
    
    solve(r-2,c+1,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r-1,c+2,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r+1,c+2,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r+2,c+1,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r+2,c-1,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r+1,c-2,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r-1,c-2,path,move+1,n);
    solve(r-2,c-1,path,move+1,n);
    
    path[r][c] = 0 ;
        
        
    }



int main (){

        
        int n;  cin>>n;
        int r;  cin>>r;
        int c;  cin>>c;
        
        vector<vector<int>> path(n,vector<int>(n,0));
        
        solve(r,c,path,1,n);
        
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

please help me to sort out why is this so??

Comment: This is why line-by-line translations from Java to C++ do not work out too well.  C++ uses value semantics, Java uses reference semantics.  If you don't know C++, you simply cannot blindly do a translation to C++ using Java as a model.

Comment: *please help me to sort out why is this so??* -- C++ is not Java, that's the simplest explanation.  It looks like you got this question from an online coding site.  Those sites expect that you know the language that you're going to implement the solution in fairly well -- well enough to not ask about the basics or make basic mistakes.  The C++ code you wrote has a lot of mistakes that unfortunately will compile successfully, but the code will not do what you believe it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Java code, the array is not copied and its reference is passed.

On the other hand, in your C++ code, the array is copied on every function calls.

To avoid this, you should use reference `vector<vector<int>>& path` (add `&`) for your function arguments.